# Given a JSONB object is there a function that produces columns for each key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

```
CREATE TABLE data (obj JSONB);
INSERT INTO data (obj) VALUES ('{"a": 1, "b": 2}'::jsonb);
INSERT INTO data (obj) VALUES ('{"a": 3, "b": 4}'::jsonb);
```

I need a query that produces the follow result:

```
 a | b 
---|---
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
```

EDIT: Answer

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM data, jsonb_to_record(obj) as x(a text, b text);
```

Comment: Do all of the `obj` columns have the same keys in their JSON?

Comment: Yes! They have the same schema! There's also a lot of them so I know I can do thing->'a' as a, thing->b as b, thing->c as c... but if there is a shortcut for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like...

```
CREATE TABLE lame (stuff jsonb);
INSERT INTO lame VALUES ('{"a" : 1, "b": 1}');
INSERT INTO lame VALUES ('{"a" : 2, "b": 2}');
SELECT stuff->'a' as "a", stuff->'b' as "b" FROM lame;
```

Find tips in the article [Faster Operations with the JSONB Data Type in PostgreSQL](https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/).

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for valid answer, I should have been more specific and said that I am away of this syntax but given all the JSONB rows have the same schema I was hoping there was a shortcut since I don't want to do ->'x' as x twenty times

Comment: @Martin8768 there is no other mechanism to my knowledge. You have to use the arrow notation.

Comment: Fair enough, that link was really useful, it had another post [When To Avoid JSONB In A PostgreSQL Schema](https://heapanalytics.com/blog/engineering/when-to-avoid-jsonb-in-a-postgresql-schema) which was very helpful for me too

Comment: I've hit that page several times. I like that piece too.

Comment: You can do it with a lateral join if the JSON schema is consistent, see the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort, I didn't find that question because it was worded differently but that is exactly what I needed, cheers!

Comment: Add that as an answer.

Comment: @Martin8768 To be fair, I found `jsonb_to_record` by browsing the PostgreSQL [JSON operator and function docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html) and worked backwards from there.